# Manage WebSocket connection on express server restart

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, websocket

Might be the title of the question does not explain the problem.

The problem is currently we have one express server listening to port 9095(for eg). Inside that server, we have implemented a `WebSocket` server whose path is `9095/wss`. Now we have around `100000` clients connected to that WebSocket server. So whenever we restart the express server the WebSocket gets disconnected and tries to reconnect(It is written on the client side(mobile app)). Whenever the server restarts all the client's request for connection and on every connection we have 4-5 mongo calls. So in this case response of so much parallel requests to `mongo` chokes our database.

What I am trying to achieve is I am thinking to move my WebSocket server to a totally new process and won't start that server until needed and will perform all the operations using IPC or whatever. But the problem is I can't change the path of WebSocket in existing clients. Is it possible somehow I can maintain same address i.e `localhost:9095/wss` on another server? Keeping in mind that a server is already running on port `9095`.

Or what can be the alternate solution for this so that I don't have to change the path and for my WebSocket server.

What should be the best approach to do this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use `nodeJS Clustering`? Your load will distribute between different process(no. of cores)

Comment: Else you can for a child process for web-socket, when ever you get a request on `/wss` send it to child process. Check this link https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/154

Comment: @Aabid I don't think clustering can be used here because it is a simple server where some `API's` are exposed. Inside that server, a WebSocket is implemented. So if we do clustering, we will have to take care of many things.

Comment: @Aabid We can do that by sending to a child process but how do we manage that on restart of the process all clients dosen't disconnect and doesn't tries to recreate connection. Is it possible to maintain those existing connections?

Comment: If you have simple http server clustering is best solution for this. Check it out https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Comment: Defiantly you have to reconnect with the server. What you can do is instead of fire queries again just save socket session in database and when user try to reconnect returned that database saved session.

Comment: We are thinking to move the webServer to a totally new server with new port and through Nginx, we will redirect that server to listen to the existing server's port. Whats say?

Comment: Did you mean complete node server or just web socket server?

Comment: A new node server which will only have the WebSocket server.

Comment: That's good thing your load will be distributed between two server.

Comment: Yes, also there will be no need of dumping existing connections on restart. On every WebSocket request, we will IPC to the existing node server.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use [redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) here save websocket id with respect to user id
>
> like `{"userId1":"socketid1","userId2":"socketId2"}` so when you app
>   is going to restart get ids back and perform your required action

```
    var ws    = require('ws'),
    nconf = require('nconf'),
    redis = require('redis');

nconf.argv()
     .env();

var server = new ws.Server({port: nconf.get('PORT')});

var sockets = {};

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('message', function(message) {            
        sockets["userId"] = socket;
    });
});

var db = redis.createClient(nconf.get("REDIS_PORT"), nconf.get("REDIS_HOST"));
if (nconf.get('REDIS_PASSWORD')) {
    db.auth(nconf.get("REDIS_PASSWORD"));
}

db.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    if (channel == 'chanel')
    {
        var a = message.split('>');
        var socket = sockets[a[0]];
        var m = a[1];
        // les messages sont supposés contenir les ID utilisateurs
        //var socket = sockets[message];
        if (socket != undefined)
        {
            socket.send(m);
        }
    }
});

db.subscribe('channel');
console.log('listening at ws://localhost:' + nconf.get('PORT'));
```